# problems when receiving form array with only one element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms

I am receiving a html form. This works fine when 2 or more elements in array, but when only one element is received I get error users[t] is null in fireBug?

```
var users = form.elements["uname[]"];

for(t in users) {
  dataString += "User: "+users[t].value+"\n"
}
```

this solved it:

```
if( typeof users.value === 'string' ) {
   users = [ users ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the variable is a string and convert it to an array:

```
if( typeof users === 'string' ) {
    users = [ users ];
}
```

For iterating arrays for-in should be avoided, that statement is meant to enumerate object properties. You could try using a better loop, something like:

```
var userCount = users.length;
for (var i = 0; i < userCount; i++) {
      dataString += "User: "+users[i].value+"\n"
}
```

You could also base a test on the length. If the object is single it will return `undefined` for length.

```
var userCount = users.length; //Get user count
if ( userCount == undefined ) { //Returned undefined if not an array.
    users = [ users ]; //Convert to array
}
```

Comment: the variable is not a string. alert(typeof(users)); tells me its an object

Comment: this for (var i = 0; i < userCount; i++) { } not work. doing users = [ users ], when only receiving one element actually works but messes up if two or more elements.

Comment: Does `var userCount = users.length;` give you the correct count? If so you could change the first bit of my example to check for one element rather than check for variable type.

Comment: if I send one element users.length is undefined, if I send two elements users.length gives me the correct count

Comment: You should be able to write that into the JS since the values are different in both contexts. I will update the example.

Comment: sry, ur first answer is actually correct! users.value is actually a string when I only send one element.

Answer (score 8):

*I know this is an old question but I stumbed across it while searching for something else. Anyway, I thought I'd provide another answer for anyone else who stumbled across this.*

Rather than checking the type to see if it is an array or not and then optionally encasing the value in a new array, you can use [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

Its syntax is

```
var new_array = old_array.concat(value1[, value2[, ...[, valueN]]])
```

where any of those values can be either an array or a single value.

In your specific case, you can start with an empty array and concatenate your form input, which will work whether you get a single value or an array:

```
var users = [].concat(form.elements["uname[]"]);
```

or

```
users = [].concat(users);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - much better solution - concise and readable